# Is it possible to run a table to table mapping scenario in parallel (multi threading)

Tags: groovy, oracle-data-integrator

Is it possible to run a table to table mapping scenario in parallel (multi threading)
we have a huge table and we already created table mapping and scenario on the mapping.
we also executing it from loadplan.
but is there way I can run the scenario in multiple threads to make the data transfer faster.
I am using groovy to script all these task.
It will be better if I get someway to script it in groovy.

Answer (score 1):

A load plan with Parallel steps or a packages with scenarios in asynchronous mode will do for the parallelism part.

An issue you might run in, depending on which KMs are used, is that the same name will be used by temporary tables in all mappings. To avoid that, select the "Use Unique Temporary Object Names" checkbox appears in the Physical tab of your mapping. It will generate a different name for these objects for each execution.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible on the ODI side, you may need some modifications on the mapping to not load any duplicate data. We have a similar flow where we use modula function on a numeric key to split source data into partitions. Then this data gets loaded into target.

To run this interface in multi-thread way, we have a package with a loop that executes the scenario asynchronously of this mapping with a MODULO_VALUE variable.

For loading data we are using oracle sqlloader utility, it is able to work in a parallel way to load data into one target table. I am not sure about if data pump utility also has this ability. But I know if you try to load data by SQL as a multithread approach you would get a `ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified` error.

As you see there is no Groovy code included in this flow, all handled by ODI mappings, packages and KMs. I hope this helps.